# windows deployment server specific dhcp scope

Tags: windows, wds

On our server we have dhcp wich has different scopes(wireless(10.0.1.0) printers(10.0.2.0) etc)
I added another scope that is called wds(10.0.7.0).

now comes the question: how can i make sure that when
I network boot it only goes installing windows if the pc has an ip in the range 10.0.7.0 and not if it is in the scope 10.0.1.0

dhcp and wds are on the same server.

hope someone can help

Comment: someone that can help me?

Comment: The easiest way would be to set up a separate vlan for the wds boot. You could potentially set up some sort of device filtering to apply the scope to only that subset of devices  (PXE clients) but I am not sure how to set that up.

Comment: This might help: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/24d9f1c9-464a-4d7e-96ab-0340898b65ad/pxe-server-on-different-subnet-from-dhcp?forum=winserverNIS

Answer (score 0):

You can configure DHCP Option 60 only on that specific scope :)

Comment: was this helpful for you?